# What does the argument @{u} mean in Git?

Tags: git

In the book "Git: Version Control for Everyone. Beginner's Guide" on page 69 there is a suggestion: "As an alternative to `git pull`, we can also use `git fetch` followed by `git merge @{u}`".

What does `@{u}` mean here?

A search in Google for `git merge @{u}` provides a link to this page https://mislav.net/2013/02/merge-vs-rebase/ where `@{u}` can also be found.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

It is a shortcut to refer to the upstream branch which the current branch is tracking. So for instance if you're on branch `topic/fix_blub` which is tracking `origin/topic/fix_blub` then `git merge @{u}` does the same thing as `git merge origin/topic/fix_blub`.

`@{u}` is part of Git's mini-language for locating revisions, which is described in detail [here](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).

Comment: how do I print the value of @{u}?

Comment: @PhilipRego `git rev-parse @{u}`

Comment: when i try to use `git reset --hard @{u}` the console doesn't execute the command but starts a new line with `>>` at the start (as if i had an open string going)

I'm Using git on Windows in powershell and i noticed a few times that i need to use different control characters than other people (e.g. ~ instead of ^) is this the same case here? do you know anything about that?

Comment: @StefanLippeck see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61490618/184546) for how to escape it in PowerShell.