# Tailing a git log

Tags: git, bash, centos

I'm reading through an old deployment script and I came across a line of bash that puzzles me.

The statement is as follows.

```
if [[ \\$(git log @{u}.. 2> /dev/null | tail -n1) != '' ]]; 
    then echo 'LOCAL BRANCH HAS UNCOMMITTED CHANGES.';
fi;
```

As far as I can tell, we're running a git log and checking to see if the output was an empty string. I could be very off, but this is why I'm asking.

```
git log @{u}.. 2> /dev/null | tail -n1
```

The above is what is the confusing part. If I run this on a local repo I get an empty string as a return value. I don't understand why though. I don't understand what the `@{u}.. 2> /dev/null` means. From what I understand the `2> /dev/null` is redirecting the possible error into a file located at `/dev/null`. But what is the rest of this line doing? ie the `@{u}`

Comment: Note that the shouted "UNCOMMITTED" word here is quite wrong: these are *committed* changes. They just are believed, by the local Git, not to have been submitted to the corresponding upstream branch `@{u}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention `2> /dev/null` redirects stderr (defined as file descriptor 2 by POSIX) to `/dev/null`, a common trick to ignore error messages.

`@{u}` is a shortcut to the upstream branch, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19474730/2515282).

`git log @{u}..` is the same as `git log @{u}..HEAD`. Double dot specifies a range of commits, e.g. all commits in `HEAD` minus all commits in `@{u}`.

So `HEAD` (local branch) minus upstream branch will give you the local commits that you have not pushed yet.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!