# git fetch origin doesnt tell me what files have been updated

Tags: git

When I use git fetch origin, I get that kind of message :

```
remote: Counting objects: 7, done.
remote: Total 7 (delta 5), reused 5 (delta 5), pack-reused 2
Unpacking objects: 100% (7/7), done.
From http://xxx/xxx
   ee28fb0..fdca511  master     -> origin/master
```

However, it doesn't tell me what files exactly did change like an svn up would.

What do I need to use here ?

Comment: [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678495/where-to-find-changes-due-to-git-fetch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting with an incorrect premise, because `git fetch` deliberately *does not* update *any* files.  This is on purpose: it allows you to `git fetch` at any time, since it never touches any of the files you may be working on.  What `git fetch` does is *add more commits* to your repository, without affecting anything that is actually checked-out in the work area.  (Git is rather Borg-like, if you are familiar with these villains from the Star Trek Next Generation series: you add the technological distinctiveness of the new commits to your git-borg collective.  Most things you do with git just wind up adding new commits, with old commits persisting forever.)

The thing is that *after* you `git fetch` you would typically run either `git merge` or, usually more appropriate, `git rebase`.  These commands *will* affect your work area files, and *now* is the time to ask what is going to change.  (Git encourages different work-flow than svn, and `git rebase` is not exactly the same as `svn up`, but is probably what you would want here.  If you never make any of your own changes, `git merge --ff-only` might be what you want here, but `git rebase` will achieve the same result.)

Because git allows and even encourages complex, distributed work-flows (where you and many other people all make many changes more or less simultaneously), viewing whose changes affect what can get complicated.  If you never make any of your own changes, though, we get a much simpler situation, with an easy to use way to see what you have just obtained from elsewhere, and what `git rebase` or `git merge --ff-only` will do.

Most likely, what you want is a `git diff --stat`, as [Mort answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36748952/1256452).  If you use `git merge` (with or without `--ff-only`), git runs a `git diff --stat` for you when it is done.  This diff demands two revision IDs and compares the tree associated with the first revision to the tree associated with the second.  The tricky part is choosing the revision IDs.  Copying them from the output of `git fetch` works, but is annoying.

Here is a different way to achieve the same result without this kind of copying:

```
git diff --stat origin/master@{1} origin/master
```

(depending on your shell you may need to quote the curly braces).

The name `origin/master@{1}` tells git to fetch the value that was stored in `origin/master` before its most recent update.  That will be the first hash `git fetch` showed, in this case `ee28fb0...`.

The name `origin/master` tells git to fetch the current value, which is what `git fetch` just set it to: in this case, `fdca511...`.

The nice thing about this is that you can go back further in time, by comparing `origin/master@{2}` to `origin/master@{1}` or to `origin/master`.

You can also compare `master`—your own branch—to any of these:

```
git diff origin/master@{1} master
```

This will show you what you changed in *your* `master`, as compared to whatever was in your `origin/master` just before you ran `git fetch`.  (Add `--stat` to get the summarized version instead of the full diff.)  Or: `git diff master origin/master` will show you what you have that is different from what you just obtained.  If you never make your own changes, that's "what they did since then".  If you *do* make your own changes, you will want to look instead at your and their *merge base*, which is where rebase and/or merge really come in, but which is another topic entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the output. You can run `git diff --stat ee28fb0...fdca511` to get the files changed on master. (Or `git log ee28fb0..fdca511`, etc.)

The thing is, `git fetch` can update lots and lots of refs. So you do not always want to see all the updates in feature branches and QA branches when all you really care about is master.