# How to see a result of git fetch?

Tags: git, git-fetch

I fetch a branch from a remote repository. How can I see that it has worked successfully? I expect that after this fetch I should have a (copy of) remote branch locally but I cannot find it (neither with `git branch` nor `git branch -r` nor `git status`). To me it looks like nothing has happened.

Comment: If there has been no output that implies to me that there is nothing to fetch. No new branches, no new commits, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to find changes due to \`git fetch\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678495/where-to-find-changes-due-to-git-fetch)

Comment: There was some output as I have executed the fetch command: "* branch              refs/changes/13/5857/2 -> FETCH_HEAD". But besides that, I do not know how to find what has changed.

Comment: Is this a follow-on from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674650/how-to-verify-that-a-remote-branch-do-exist?  Did my thing about not configuring a remote turn out to be correct?  (If so, it's the answer to this new question.)

Answer (score 2):

First, to be sure to get an output, whether new branches or commits are actually found on the remote end, you can go for the verbose fetch :

```
git fetch -v
```

Then any non-updated remote branch will show up in the output as (for example)

```
= [up to date]       my_awesome_branch      -> origin/my_awesome_branch
= [up to date]       yet_another_branch     -> origin/yet_another_branch
```

---

But beyond this, even after having successful fetched and now having fresh references in your local repo, note that **at this point only remote-tracking branches are updated** to reflect the state of their counterparts on the remote end.

Your local branches, however, are still in the state they were before the fetch operation.

With this fetch output example :

```
$ git fetch
remote: Counting objects: 143, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (143/143), done.
remote: Total 143 (delta 118), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (143/143), 16.54 KiB | 1.65 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (118/118), completed with 53 local objects.
From ssh://<repoNameRedacted>
 * [new branch]          feature-2541 -> origin/feature-2541
   433c28824..9924cc527  bugfix-9891 -> origin/bugfix-9891
```

If you were to now work on bugfix-9891 and get the most recent work, doing

```
git checkout bugfix-9891
```

...would point your HEAD at this local branch, allowing you to work on it, but you would **not** have the most recent commits, even though you fetched them just beforehand. They're in the remote-tracking `origin/bugfix-9891` but still not in *your* local version `bugfix-9891`.

To actually incorporate these changes and work on top of them, you'll have to

```
git checkout bugfix/9891
git merge origin/bugfix/9891
```

---

Let's also note that there is a very common (though by no means necessary) way to automate the [fetch + merge with remote] process, namely :

```
git checkout bugfix/9891
git pull
```

Answer (score 1):

After you fetched, to see what remote "master" has compared to your local "master", you ask Git to show you exactly this:

```
git log origin/master ^master
```

which means «all commits reachable from "origin/master" which do not include commits reachable from "master"» or, alternatively

```
git log master..origin/master
```

also, `git diff master origin/master`
 seems to address the question very simply I think.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you meant to do GIT PULL, not GIT FETCH.

Or perhaps you meant to do GIT CLONE.

GIT FETCH will not change any files in your current branch, it will only update your repository.