# git sparseCheckout and rev-list command

Tags: git, github

I am trying to use the `git rev-list` command in a repo that I have setup a sparse checkout in.
Repo was set up as follows:

```
mkdir -p /opt/apcu
git -C /opt/apcu/ init
git -C /opt/apcu/ remote add -f origin git@github.com:krakjoe/apcu.git
git -C /opt/apcu/ config core.sparseCheckout true
echo "apc.php" >> /opt/apcu/.git/info/sparse-checkout
git -C /opt/apcu/ config branch.master.remote origin
git -C /opt/apcu/ config branch.master.merge refs/heads/master
git -C /opt/apcu/ pull origin
```

Now I would like to check for any changes in the repo:

```
$ git rev-list HEAD...origin
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD...origin': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Any idea why I am getting the above error?

This is the bash script that is failing for me. The idea was to check for any changes to the remote repos and then pull them down. The reason I go through the trouble of checking for commits is because another function in the script runs an installation depending on what is updated.

```
# Do not fetch or pull "master" this is not always the default branch you have checked out.
# Omitting the branch to fetch or pull will pull the default.
for i in "${repo_array[@]}"; do
    git -C "$i" fetch origin &>/dev/null
    # Get rid of errors because git reports differences in repo as errors.
    commits=$(git -C "$i" rev-list HEAD...origin --count 2>/dev/null)

    if (( commits != 0 )); then
        git -C "$i" pull origin &>/dev/null
        # Run the installer function to install new versions
        installer
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`origin` is not a reference, but a remote URL

For instance: `origin/master` would be a reference to the last fetched remote `master` HEAD.

```
git rev-list HEAD...origin/master
```

In your case, since master is not always the branch you are pulling, you would use:

```
commits=$(git -C "$i" rev-list HEAD...@{u} --count 2>/dev/null)
```

With `@{u}` (or `@{upstream}`) being the shortcut for the upstream branch associated with the current branch.

Comment: So if I had a different branch than `master` checked out I would need to do: `git rev-list HEAD...origin/v3.3/dev`

Comment: @steveH After a fetch, yes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10685691/6309. After a pull, this is trickier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12631371/6309

Comment: I updated my question to help show the code that I am trying to run. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @steveH I know: I have already updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `origin` *can* mean `origin/HEAD`, which *can* be a symbolic reference pointing to one of your other `origin/*` remote-tracking names.  If `origin/HEAD` exists, and you use the name `origin` by itself the way you are doing,<sup>1</sup>  See [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), and in particular the six-step process for resolving a revision specifier; note that step 6 consists of adding `ref/remotes/` to the front, and `/HEAD` to the end, of whatever name you provided and attempting to look that up.

Having run `git remote add origin`, you can run `git remote set-head origin` (with whatever options you like) to set the `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` symbolic reference.  But unless you really want to query the remote Git to set your `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` to match their `HEAD`, it's almost certainly *much* better to just use an explicit `origin/master`, or `origin/other-specified-name`, here.  In fact, in a script, it's wise to use fully-qualified names: `refs/remotes/origin/master`, for instance.

Using the `@{upstream}` or `@{u}` modifier on a branch name is probably your best bet, though; see [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61044284/1256452).

---

<sup>1</sup>The specifiers in a compound item like `HEAD..origin` amount to three tokens: `HEAD`, `..`, and `origin`.  By "by itself", I mean that you're using `origin` as a token in this way, and not as part of a larger token such as `origin/master`.  You can also write, e.g., `origin~12` here; the three tokens are `origin`, `~`, and `12`.  While Git's revision parser is ad-hoc, rather than using a formal grammar with [lexemes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14954721/1256452), it *functions* like one.